# Dropbox Linux Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, dropbox

Everything worked great for a year, and the server was untouched. All of a sudden my automation file transfers depending on Dropbox didn't work anymore. The dropbox tray icon is unavailable so I try to run the daemon and get segmentation fault. So I tried to reinstall:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.dropbox
$ cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
$ ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

And still get segmentation fault, how do I fix this?

strace output: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f0151e86665bc6842c8#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of Dropbox. Use git or some other reasonable deployment strategy.

Comment: uninstall dropbox, time to try a good old version of bittorrent sync

Comment: I said _reasonable_.

Comment: Maybe you must run daemon with root user?

Comment: run daemon as root user failed

Comment: Use strace to see where the daemon fails. This will narrow down your search. You can also post the strace result here.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6f0151e86665bc6842c8#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I increased the physical RAM from 4GB to 8GB, and Dropbox is starting up without segmentation fault anymore.